# How to tweet using twitter api?

Tags: android, twitter

I am developing an app in which User can tweet some predefined text. I have read many of tutorials but could not find the proper solution .Can any body please help me to do this via some tutorials or some example.

Comment: i have read http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-post-twitter-status-from-android/  , http://abhinavasblog.blogspot.in/2011/06/for-all-my-code-thirsty-friends-twitter.html

Comment: in the first tutorial 02-17 18:29:56.832: WARN/System.err(1484): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Host is unresolved: api.twitter.com:443 there ia an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/). It works with Android. There are some [usage examples](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html).

A direct example on how to tweet on Android (assumes a Twitter account is available on device which means a Twitter client is present): http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/04/using-twitter4j-to-tweet-in-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Every body for support all the tutorial I have read are very good .But that was my mistake .I have not given the read and write permission in developer account . Now I have done it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save yourself from the hassles of using twitter4j api where the use of oAuth etc. is required, you can try using a **web-intent** in a WebView shown in a dialog.
Have a look on the following tutorial
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents

You will be able to tweet once the username and password has been entered and saved. Although the use of Web-Intent might be discouraged, but it's easiest hack you can try.