# Embed old tweet using api

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, twitter

I'm trying to embed the most recent tweet/s from a user's public stream. I did this with

```
$.getJSON('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/'+user+'.json?callback=?', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    ...
}
```

This doesn't work anymore. I thought it was due to the tweets all being old, but after swapping the name out for a active account it didn't work either.

I do not want to manually embed a tweet. I preferably do not want to use a twitter widget.

I've tried [tweet.seaofclouds.com](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com)'s twitter plugin, but it also doesn't find the old tweets ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WwfEr/4/))

So what I need is a method to show the latest tweet no matter the age for this user: [@nietopmeisjes](https://twitter.com/nietopmeisjes)

Not a duplicate of:
[How to tweet using twitter api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329046/how-to-tweet-using-twitter-api) (this is for android app)
[How to tweet using Twitter api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404826/how-to-tweet-using-twitter-api) (this is about iOS app)

Comment: Looks completely fine to me.  I'm seeing the tweets in the jFiddle.  Twitter has an API limit/hour.  So your IP may have gone over that limit.

Comment: Yeah Justice, I had an active user's name in there instead of the one I need with the old tweets. The link has been fixed (it's now broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter has [released](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api) a new version of api, 1.1. And now each API endpoint requires authentication via OAuth.

You can still use version 1 by changing the url to `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline` but this will stop working on March 2013 as noted in the link.

With 1.1 you have to use server side application to get OAuth token and retrieve your tweets. Make sure you follow the [Display Requirements](https://dev.twitter.com/terms/display-requirements) and be careful of new api limits. <s>Or just remove twitter widget from your app.</s>

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Changing the url doesn't work though: http://jsfiddle.net/yTRGK/1/